# How to update MySql Database from threading in java

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, mysql-workbench

Hi i have a java program which fetch json data from one website and we store that json data in our local Mysql database. From the local Mysql database we are using those values for some calculations. I wants to update my database after every 2 hours using API from the website. I don't know how to do that and I have never done it before. I can give the Structure of my database tell me if there is something i need to do in mysql data base or I have to use threading concept. Please suggest some tutorial or example.

I have a table Student with fields **First_name**, **last_name** and **Roll_no** I have not included any time or date. tell me if someone have some idea regarding the problem I'm facing .
I have used **JDBC** for database connection.
Thanks In advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, how to do the actual update, or how to trigger a refresh every 2 hours...?

Comment: This question is just too broad.  You will need to show more work and refine it before SO can help.

Comment: there is a website which throughs some API. I'm catching those API in my Java program and storing the data in my local data base . Now I want that my local database that is my Mysql database will update after every 2 hours from that API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to schedule your Java application for execution every two hours.

a) Write a cronjob to do so.

b) Create a `Timer` within your Java application which fires every two hours to restart the "update process"